# Autoclicker randomly stops (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

Basically i'm having a problem with my autoclicker, it does work but after a while it will randomly stop, if i press again it will work, here is my code jw what could be going wrong:

```
    Private Sub click_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles click.Tick
    If (toggleBool = True And mDown = True) Then
        mouse_event(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        mouse_event(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub mHook_Mouse_Left_Down(ByVal ptLocat As System.Drawing.Point) Handles mHook.Mouse_Left_Down
    mDown = True
    If (toggleBool = True And mDown = True) Then
        Dim intLowNumber = CInt(minBar.Value * 10)
        Dim intUpperNumber = CInt(maxBar.Value * 10)
        Dim rand As New Random


        Dim cps As Integer = rand.Next(intLowNumber, intUpperNumber + 1)
        click.Interval = cps
        click.Enabled = True
        click.Start()

        If (jitter = True And mDown = True) Then
            Dim x As Integer = rand.Next(Cursor.Position.X - 3, Cursor.Position.X + 3)
            Dim y As Integer = rand.Next(Cursor.Position.Y - 3, Cursor.Position.Y + 3)
            Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)
        End If
    End If
End Sub 
    Private Sub mHook_Mouse_Left_Up(ByVal ptLocat As System.Drawing.Point) Handles mHook.Mouse_Left_Up
    mDown = False
    If (toggleBool = True) Then
        click.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and I had to put a small delay between the mouse press and release.

Comment: i did this and this decreases the cps by a ton and also doesn't stop clicking sometimes, http://prntscr.com/fbn684

Comment: I can't see your link, I had to put Threading.Thread.Sleep with a small amount between. It does lower the click count. Maybe this won't work for you. Mine was for those web clicker game. Also, make sure it's not slow than your timer.